# Excel warning when opening .xls exported table with javascript

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I am using a script that exports a content of a pivot table to a .xls excel file. The problem is that everytime that I open this file, Excel gives the following warning message, although it successfully opens it:

*"The file you are trying to open, '[filename]', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"*

Is there a way to export the file without having this warning?

I am using [orb.js](http://orbjs.net/index.html). The javascript code that exports is below:

```
function(_dereq_, module, exports) {

        var utils = _dereq_('./orb.utils');
        var uiheaders = _dereq_('./orb.ui.header');
        var themeManager = _dereq_('./orb.themes');

        var uriHeader = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
        var docHeader = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' +
            '<head>' +
            '<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' +
            '<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>' +
            ' <x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
            '  <x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
            '   <x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '    <x:Name>###sheetname###</x:Name>' +
            '    <x:WorksheetOptions>' +
            '     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>' +
            '     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>' +
            '     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>' +
            '    </x:WorksheetOptions>' +
            '   </x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
            '  </x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
            '  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>' +
            '  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>' +
            ' </x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
            '</xml><![endif]-->' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body>';
        var docFooter = '</body></html>';

        module.exports = function(pgridwidget) {

            var config = pgridwidget.pgrid.config;
            var currTheme = themeManager.current();
            currTheme = currTheme === 'bootstrap' ? 'white' : currTheme;
            var override = currTheme === 'white';

            var buttonTextColor = override ? 'black' : 'white';
            var themeColor = themeManager.themes[currTheme];
            var themeFadeout = themeManager.utils.fadeoutColor(themeColor, 0.1);

            var buttonStyle = 'style="font-weight: bold; color: ' + buttonTextColor + '; background-color: ' + themeColor + ';" bgcolor="' + themeColor + '"';
            var headerStyle = 'style="background-color: ' + themeFadeout + ';" bgcolor="' + themeFadeout + '"';

            function createButtonCell(caption) {
                return '<td ' + buttonStyle + '><font color="' + buttonTextColor + '">' + caption + '</font></td>';
            }

            function createButtons(buttons, cellsCountBefore, cellsCountAfter, prefix) {
                var i;
                var str = prefix || '<tr>';
                for (i = 0; i < cellsCountBefore; i++) {
                    str += '<td></td>';
                }

                str += buttons.reduce(function(tr, field) {
                    return (tr += createButtonCell(field.caption));
                }, '');

                for (i = 0; i < cellsCountAfter; i++) {
                    str += '<td></td>';
                }
                return str + '</tr>';
            }

            var cellsHorizontalCount = Math.max(config.dataFields.length + 1, pgridwidget.layout.pivotTable.width);

            var dataInicioFilter = (pgridwidget.pgrid.config.dataInicio==null) ? '' :
                                   '<tr><td><font color=\"#ccc\">Data Início</font></td>' + '<td ' + buttonStyle +
                                   '><font color="' + buttonTextColor + '">' + pgridwidget.pgrid.config.dataInicio +
                                   '</font></td>'+'</tr>';

            var dataFimFilter = (pgridwidget.pgrid.config.dataFim==null) ? '' :
                   '<tr><td><font color=\"#ccc\">Data Fim</font></td>' + '<td ' + buttonStyle +
                   '><font color="' + buttonTextColor + '">' + pgridwidget.pgrid.config.dataFim +
                   '</font></td>'+'</tr>';

            var comissaoFilter = (pgridwidget.pgrid.config.comissao==0) ? '' :
                   '<tr><td><font color=\"#ccc\">Comissão (R$)</font></td>' + '<td ' + buttonStyle +
                   '><font color="' + buttonTextColor + '">' + pgridwidget.pgrid.config.comissao +
                   '</font></td>'+'</tr>';

            var dataFields = createButtons(config.dataFields,
                0,
                cellsHorizontalCount - config.dataFields.length,
                '<tr><td><font color="#3a2c2c">Dados</font></td>'
            );

            var sep = '<tr><td style="height: 22px;" colspan="' + cellsHorizontalCount + '"></td></tr>';

            var columnFields = createButtons(config.columnFields,
                pgridwidget.layout.rowHeaders.width,
                cellsHorizontalCount - (pgridwidget.layout.rowHeaders.width + config.columnFields.length)
            );

            var columnHeaders = (function() {
                var str = '';
                var j;
                for (var i = 0; i < pgridwidget.columns.headers.length; i++) {
                    var currRow = pgridwidget.columns.headers[i];
                    var rowStr = '<tr>';
                    if (i < pgridwidget.columns.headers.length - 1) {
                        for (j = 0; j < pgridwidget.layout.rowHeaders.width; j++) {
                            rowStr += '<td></td>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        rowStr += config.rowFields.reduce(function(tr, field) {
                            return (tr += createButtonCell(field.caption));
                        }, '');
                    }

                    rowStr += currRow.reduce(function(tr, header) {
                        var value = header.type === uiheaders.HeaderType.DATA_HEADER ? header.value.caption : header.value;
                        return (tr += '<td ' + headerStyle + ' colspan="' + header.hspan(true) + '" rowspan="' + header.vspan(true) + '">' + value + '</td>');
                    }, '');
                    str += rowStr + '</tr>';
                }
                return str;
            }());

            var rowHeadersAndDataCells = (function() {
                var str = '';
                var j;
                for (var i = 0; i < pgridwidget.rows.headers.length; i++) {
                    var currRow = pgridwidget.rows.headers[i];
                    var rowStr = '<tr>';
                    rowStr += currRow.reduce(function(tr, header) {
                        return (tr += '<td ' + headerStyle + ' colspan="' + header.hspan(true) + '" rowspan="' + header.vspan(true) + '">' + header.value + '</td>');
                    }, '');
                    var dataRow = pgridwidget.dataRows[i];
                    rowStr += dataRow.reduce(function(tr, dataCell, index) {
                        var formatFunc = config.dataFields[index = index % config.dataFields.length].formatFunc;
                        var value = dataCell.value == null ? '' : formatFunc ? formatFunc()(dataCell.value) : dataCell.value;
                        return (tr += '<td>' + value + '</td>');
                    }, '');
                    str += rowStr + '</tr>';
                }
                return str;
            }());

            function toBase64(str) {
                return utils.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
            }

            return uriHeader +
                toBase64(docHeader +
                    '<table>' + dataInicioFilter + dataFimFilter + comissaoFilter + dataFields + sep + columnFields + columnHeaders + rowHeadersAndDataCells + '</table>' +
                    docFooter);
        };
    }
```

Comment: What is the warning from Excel?

Comment: In my case I am getting something similar, with the error: `The format and extension of *.xls don't match. The file could be corrupt or unsafe.`. But the header I am adding to the export is indeed `ms-excel`.

Comment: @StevenWestmoreland I have updated the post with the warning.

Comment: @CatalinIancu let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara  Hi Alexandre, did you find a solution please for this issue ?  I am struggling for many days to resolve this excel pop up without success. Thank you

Comment: @JuniorDev I am sorry, but I didn't find anything to solve that.